# StartActivity call requires permissions problems

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

[I follow this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PHDcQOGFtg) Previously, It has no problems .

Today I try again , but it has some problem with it.[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eZUF.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fooddeliverycaller">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After API 23, User has to explicitly give approval to any permission that may access user's confidential data. Such permissions contains [**Calendar, Camera, Contact, Location, Microphone, Phone, Sensor, SMS, Storage**.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)

Below is the code I taken from [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) with some modification.

```
private void callNumber() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
              // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
              // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
              // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        }
    } else {
        //This is for lower version <23
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + MyCellNumber);
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

And then override below method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + MyCellNumber));
                startActivity(callIntent);
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add (runtime) permissions check. Starting from Android API 23 and higher, you need to ask for permissions to do certain tasks(Ex: calls, location info...) during runtime. To do so, simply, click on this code:

```
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Go to the red warning triangle/sign left to your code. Click on it, and click on add permission check. Now when you run your app, a "dialog" will pop up, and ask the user to allow the app to make calls.

Hope this helps. For more info see this links:

[Android permission checks](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

or check out this previously answered question (as suggested by @CommonsWare):

[Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it)

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
Intent.ACTION_DIAL
```

instead of **Intent.ACTION_CALL**. Intent.ACTION_DIAL which prepopulates the dialer with the number you pass it. It doesn't require permission.

Hope it solves the problem!